# Interpreting a quadratic logarithmic term

Tags: regression, stata, multiple-regression, interpretation, logarithm

Given the regression model

$y=\beta_0 + 300*ln(x_1) - 15 * (ln(x_1))^2 + \beta_3*x_2 + ... + u $

$x$ ranges from 1 000 to 30 000 (6.9 to 10.3 on a logarithmic scale). How to interpret the diminishing effect that $x_1$ has on $y$? Is it possible to interpret it for small changes in $x_1$ analog to a "normal" quadratic term, i.e. the partial effect can be calculated as

$\Delta y = [\beta_1 - 2*\beta_2 * ln(x1)]$

and the maximum (turning point) as $x_{1} = - \beta_1 / (2*\beta_2)$, which would yield 300 / 30 = 10 with e^10=22026? How to give a meaningful and illustrative interpretation of the effect? For example, the effect of a 1% increase of $x_1$ or going from 20 000 to 21 000?

#### Edit

Thank you for the code and sorry for the delayed response. I managed to plot
the marginal effect of x1 but decided to use the plot of the actual and predicted values of y against x1 while holding all other variables at their mean using the following Stata code:

```
reg y ln(x1) (ln(x1))^2 x2 x3 x4 x5
adjust x2 x3 x4 x5 if e(sample), gen(predict)
twoway line predict x1, sort || scatter y x1
```

I think this illustrates the effect of x1 on y really well and the plot is
easy to understand despite the quadratic logarithmic term in the regression model.

Comment: In R the `effects` package in R can easily help with interpreting such coefficients by producing the appropriate graphs. See http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Misc/effects/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the derivative that you want actually $\frac{dy}{dx_{1}}=\frac{300}{x_{1}}-\frac{30}{x_{1}}\ln x_{1}$? Your derivative is the change in $y$ for a small change in $\ln x_{1}$. I think it's probably easier to think about about changing $x_{1}$ on the original (non-logged) scale. That shows that the marginal effect of $x_{1}$ starts out positive for small $x_1$ and declines steeply until $x_{1}=e^{10}$ and is negative for $x_{1} \gt e^{10}$.

Here's some Stata code to make the graphs you asked about below. There might be a more elegant way to do the labels on the original scale, but that's all I got:

```
#delimit;
clear all;
set more off;

sysuse auto, clear;

gen lmpg=ln(mpg);

reg price c.lmpg##c.lmpg;

/* yhat at x of 18, 20 & 25 */
margins, at(lmpg=(`=ln(18)' `=ln(20)' `=ln(25)'));

sum lmpg;
local mean = r(mean);
local sd = r(sd);

/* yhat at mean of ln(x) and at mean plus 1 sd */
margins, at(lmpg=(`mean' `=`mean'+`sd''));
marginsplot, xlabels(`mean' "`=round(exp(`mean'),,01)'" `=`mean'+`sd'' "`=round(exp(`mean'+`sd'),.01)'");  


/* The MARGINAL effect of x on y at mean and mean of ln(x) plus 1sd */
margins, dydx(lmpg) at(lmpg=(`mean' `=`mean'+`sd''));
marginsplot, xlabels(`mean' "`=round(exp(`mean'),.01)'" `=`mean'+`sd'' "`=round(exp(`mean'+`sd'),.01)'");
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the minimum of that derivative is $\frac{30}{e^{11}}<0$, at $x=e^{11}$, but maybe Will's calculus is better that mine.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I think Will is right because of x1*=e^ (a/2b). However, I am not sure how to best present the result to the reader. I created a plot of the predicted values of y against ln(x1) while holding all other variables at their mean. Do you have a recommendation how to best discuss the numbers? Preferably, I would like to give two examples, thereby illustrating the changing effect but the discussion of a marginal change from 10000 to 10001 is hardly illuminating.

Comment: I think a lot of this depends on the domain. If there are some salient levels for $x_{1}$, you can report $y$ or $frac{dy}{dx}$ for those values or graph the curve you talked with the salient values labeled. Personally, I prefer to use the unlogged scale axis labels, but then scale the axis (see this paper for an example: http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0032). Another approach would be to take the mean or median of $x_{1}\pm\sigma$, and report what a standard deviation increase above the central moment would do to $y$ in your model.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. It seems that it is not that easy to scale the axis in Stata. I find your second approach particularly interesting. Do you have a suggestion or a link of how to do that in Stata? Is there an ado file that offers an easy to implement solution?

Comment: I edited my response above to give you an example.

Comment: Thank you for the Stata code. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that I only use Stata 9/10 and hence cannot use this command. I guess the alternative is doing this by hand? This seems to be very error prone, especially since –mfx does not recognize that the second variable is simply the quadratic of the first one.

Comment: Maybe you can try this with the user-written command margeff from ssc. I am not sure if it lets you use factor variables since they were introduced in Stata 11. The other approach is to code it manually like this:`#delimit; sysuse auto, clear;
gen lmpg=ln(mpg);
gen lmpg2=ln(mpg)^2;
reg price lmpg lmpg2;
sum mpg;
tw (function y = _b[lmpg] + 2*_b[lmpg2]*ln(x), range(`r(min)' `r(max)'));`

Comment: I think the backquotes are getting screwed up above, but I am not sure how to fix it.